# ¿Hay algún "hater" suelto por Spanish Language?

Tags: soporte, votos, votos-negativos

Me estoy dando cuenta de que, desde hace unos días, todas mis respuestas en las preguntas más activas reciben por sistema un -1. Examinando las preguntas en cuestión, he visto que algunas incluso tienen -1 tanto en la propia pregunta como en todas y cada una de las respuestas dadas ([ejemplo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17118/es-correcto-mantener-de-y-el-separados-en-alg%C3%BAn-caso)). Esto me indica que debe de haber algún *hater* suelto por el sitio.

La pregunta es, ¿a quién hemos incordiado? ¿Es posible saber quién se está dedicando a esto? ¿Es posible prevenirlo? ¿Es esto parte de la idiosincrasia de los sitios de Stack Exchange?

Comment: Interesante lectura: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/209901). Estoy comentándolo con los moderadores de [se]. Cualquier novedad te aviso.

Comment: Mis últimos votos en contra, repentinamente numerosos, son a respuestas en preguntas tuyas.

Comment: Todos esos votos negativos vienen del mismo usuario, que los estuvo haciendo durante un par de días de una forma bastante metódica.

Comment: @fedorqui por los documentos que enlazaste, ¿no se supone que Stack Exchange tiene sistemas de protección automática ante este tipo de situaciones? De hecho lo primero que te recomiendan es no hacer lo que yo hice (poner un aviso en meta), sino esperar a que el sistema haga correcciones automáticas.

Comment: Los tiene, pero solo para cuando los votos se realizan en poco tiempo. En este caso, se dieron en rachas de 4-5 en distintos momentos del día, lo que dio pie a que el sistema no los viera como _serial downvoting_. Tal y como se comenta en [What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212339/209901), es mejor gestionarlo de forma privada a través de _flags_. Ya lo puse en manos de quien puede hacer algo, así que en breve debería haber novedades.

Comment: @fedorqui ¡muchas gracias por tu tiempo y dedicación!

Answer (score 3):

Como puedes ver en la [pestaña *Reputation* de tu perfil](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/carlos-alejo?tab=reputation&sort=time) seleccionando el día de ayer 6 de julio de 2016, hay una entrada del tipo:

```
91  18:58   removed User was removed (learn more)
```

El enlace de [learn more](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/user-was-removed) da más pistas al respecto.

Esto también ocurre en los perfiles de otros usuarios y designa que un usuario ha sido eliminado. Se da la circunstancia de que es el usuario que había realizado estos votos negativos, que circunstancialmente (y no sé si tiene algo que ver) pidió que se le eliminara.

De forma general, es bueno tener en cuenta que el voto es totalmente libre y secreto. No hace falta ni decir por qué úno vota a favor o en contra y cada cual puede tener sus motivos para hacerlo.

Ahora bien, tal y como hablamos en los comentarios Stack Exchange dispone de mecanismos para amortiguar comportamientos excesivos, así como opciones para que los administradores podamos detectar patrones sospechosos.

Comment: Sí, me di cuenta anoche y pensé que tendría que ver algo con esto, aunque me extrañó que se hubiera llegado al extremo de eliminar por completo al usuario. Si me dices que el usuario ha pedido su eliminación voluntaria, me quedo más tranquilo.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo sí, a mí también me sorprendió (y entristeció) ver su petición.

Comment: En este caso además de los votos negativos ese usuario había dado muchos votos positivos ya que su eliminación dio como resultado neto una disminución en la reputación de Carlos Alejo de -91. Parece que no era un "hater" sino un "lover" jajajaja

Comment: @DGaleano efectivamente. El usuario tuvo un par de rachas de  votar negativamente 40 posts en un día, pero el resto de tiempo su comportamiento fue ejemplar.

Comment: Tal vez tuvo algún despiste con su cuenta (al utilizar un ordenador compartido, p. ej.).

Comment: @cdlvcdlv si bien puede ser, me extrañaría. Alguien capaz de votar negativamente en rachas de 2-3 cada vez sabe perfectamente cómo funciona esto para evitar que se le invaliden los votos. Además, el hecho de que se haga en distintos momentos quita peso a la hipótesis de que fuera un despiste, pues serían muchos despistes juntos : )

Comment: ¿Y si el usuario legítimo siguió usando su cuenta desde el ordenador propio mientras el gamberro usaba las _cookies_ del ordenador ajeno en el que entró el usuario?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv no lo creo. Cuando votas negativamente una respuesta pierdes reputación, así que el usuario principal se habría dado cuenta si de repente perdía 5, 10 o 20 puntos.